# AWS S3 Upload files by part in chunks smaller than 5MB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way, how to upload files smaller parts than in 5MB? Multipart upload requires the size of chunks to be larger than 5MB (excluding last one). However i am working with chunks of 32KB.

Is there a way how to upload chunks of lesser size or am i left with storing my chunks until they reach 5MB in size and then use multipart upload?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

While you can't set the part/chunk size to be smaller than 5MB, you can make it bigger. If you're using the AWS CLI tool to upload the files, you can set the part/chunk size as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html.

In addition, you can set the multipart threshold so that files smaller than the threshold are not uploaded using the multipart process. You'll need to change the settings between uploading to the various buckets.